# Using type predicates in class methods in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types, predicate

I have a class defined like this

```
class Foo {
   value: string | null;
   constructor(){
      this.value = null;
   }
   private ensureValueExists():this.value is string{ //type predicate is not legal
      this.value = "bar";
      return true;
   }
   doStuffWithValue(){
      this.ensureValueExists();
      return 5 + this.value;  //ERROR, this.value can be null
   }
}
```

I would like for the ensureValueExists method to be able to tell to the compiler that this.value is indeed a string and safe to use.
Is there a special syntax to use or is it no doable with TS at the moment for methods ?

Comment: `this.value ??= "bar";`

Comment: I would prefer to get my type predicate to work, so i don't have to add guards everywhere.

Comment: If you can ensure that `value` will be initialised later but still would be available before "real code" (non-initialisation code) access it, then you can note it as `value!: string`. If you want null-safe access you can say `this.value ?? "fallback"`. If you want to make sure you produce an object where `value` is treated as non-null you can have a separate interface. It's a bit hard to say which is the correct choice here.

Comment: "I would prefer to get my type predicate to work, so i don't have to add guards everywhere." But you'll still have to add assertions everywhere

Comment: I don't understand, with the solution from jcalz it works without a non-null assertion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use an [assertion method](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) which narrows `this`. Support for that isn't particularly clear from the documentation, although a [commit](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/32695/commits/0599f848575dcfbda5730c446003f4e59411446d) associated with [microsoft/TypeScript#32695](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/32695), the PR implementing assertion functions, demonstrates that it's possible.

So in your case it would look like:

```
  private ensureValueExists(): asserts this is { value: string } {
    this.value = "bar";
  }
```

(Note that you can't return anything in an assertion function/method), and then the following works:

```
  doStuffWithValue() {
    this.ensureValueExists();
    return 5 + this.value;  // okay
  }
}
```

There are definitely [caveats](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34596#issuecomment-544208587) associated with assertion functions and methods, but since you're only operating on `this`, you aren't running into them here.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1oDcwgK4FMAuaCAFwCcBLAOwHNoAfaa3EEAbnWmHmrPNzBS8cgAoAlCi4ZSAC0oQAdNjz5oAXmasOXAL5cADlWyk1+PrnL4AajgIBRAB4LSECcUgR85V9DkLoAOQsOyISChp6XSkMGXklFQINaAAiACMwchTODH0MABN4AGVSXAAzMoB1SjlbVQkY2P8lcwhLG1CnFzdxHNirUvJqaABWaABqP3jlUPYMAHp56HgAazAATz1UfVQgA)

Comment: I don't understand how this is even possible. Nice hack.

Comment: I am getting `Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'void'.ts(2322)` in my editor when trying this but if I remove the `asserts` keyword the type predicate works.

Comment: > (Note that you can't return anything in an assertion function/method)

Comment: An assertion function should throw or return `void`. Hence, if you need a return value, the classic predicate would be better e.g. `private isValueString(): this is {value: string} { return typeof this.value === 'string' ? true : false }`

Comment: If  one _does_ want/need to return something from the function, just leave out the `asserts` part of the predicate.  eg. `isValid(): this is { value: string } { return this.value != null; }`

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is called a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards). It can be used to narrow down the type of its parameter, but nothing outside of that. For example, even this code won't work:

```
let value: unknown

function isValueString(): value is string { // Cannot find parameter 'value'.
    return typeof value === 'string'
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/DYUwLgBAbghsCuIBcF4DsDWaD2B3NAsAFDEBm6AxmAJbZoTUDOAanIgMpgBO1aA5gAoAlClgIQDRhEbdefCAG8IAemUQAwjDQ5IpXgBMIABxhcYAW3AguEAORjEtgHTEIbiF3Dwu9MAE8jEGxSaDYJAF5IuxkefltiAF9iIA)

There is also the [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functionsxkefltiAF9iIA) syntax, which you probably meant to use in the first place. However, that has the same limitation as above, you can't use it on anything else than function parameters:

```
let value: unknown

function ensureValueIsString(): asserts value is string { // Cannot find parameter 'value'.
    value ??= 'bar'
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/DYUwLgBAbghsCuIBcF4DsDWaD2B3NAsAFDEBm6AxmAJbZoTUDOAanIgMpgBO1aA5gAoAlChiNGILmEbQ2IBjMbdefCAG8IAek0QAwjDQ5IpXgBMIABxhcYAW3CSIAclgIQTgHTEIP2W4gA-AEAvM4ARtZOxAC%20xEA)

Comment: Yes i know, what i was asking is if it is doable with methods.

Comment: I don't think so. How about setting a default value in the constructor and making `value` non-nullable?

Comment: It is doable with methods, if you narrow `this` (which is an implicit parameter); see my answer above or below or wherever it is