# Detect the correct conditional return type in Typescript class methods

Tags: typescript, types, predicate

I found this similar questions: [Using type predicates in class methods in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68289684/using-type-predicates-in-class-methods-in-typescript)

But the answer does not include returning a value. For example, what I would like to do is fairly simple:

```
const resolver = new Resolver(data);
if (resolver.hasMatch()) {
   // Invalid type "string | undefined" of template literal expression.
   console.log(`This is the match: ${resolver.getMatch()}`);
} else {
   console.log('`getMatch` returns `undefined` (no match)');
}
```

Basically, if you call `hasMatch` the value of `getMatch` is a string, otherwise it's `undefined`.

I tried a few different things:

1. using `assert`: `public hasMatch(): asserts this is { getBestMatch(): string } {` but the following type problem occurs when trying to return a value: `Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'void'.`
2. using the same syntax, without `assert` (this was one of the comments on the other question): `public hasMatch(): this is ResolveAcceptLanguage & { getBestMatch(): string } {` but it does not work. It looks like it's adding an overload (in VScode) but I can't see it...

Is there a way to do this without using `as string` in the example I provided?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I am following.  But it appears that you are attempting to type-narrow by redefining the signature of a class method - which seems a little strange.   I'm assuming that this is a simplification of a more complex implementation?  Otherwise, I would suggest that your if statement should instead just check for the truthy result of resolver.getMatch() !== undefined - which I would think give you the result you are looking for without the need of implmenting `hasMatch`

Comment: Yes, I don't know what the right approach is.. but basically, I'm trying to avoid using an `as string` since calling the `hasMatch` ensures that `getMatch` returns a string

Comment: You are right `resolver.getMatch() !== undefined` would work, but its less intuitive than `hasMatch` - I was hoping that there was a solution for this use case

Comment: I think a type guard here could work?

Comment: @catgirlkelly how would it work in this use case? I could not find a way, especially if we want to have a single class method

Comment: I was hoping something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WoGdjW) could do the trick... but clearly it doesn't... Why does TypeScript type `r` as `Resolver & ...` instead?

Comment: @catgirlkelly very nice, I was trying to get `Omit` working but it looks like its still just adding an overload like the 2nd thing I tried in my question - what we would need is some sort of overwrite rather than overload

Comment: I think it's just how TypeScript works with functions when we try to do this because if we see [here](https://tsplay.dev/w2aOxW) clearly the private obscure `__r__` property is being narrowed correctly, but the type of `getMatch` is not.

Comment: @catgirlkelly even with your proposal, I'm not sure I understand if it can change the type conditionally? because if `hasMatch` is false, we actually want the type to become `undefined`

Comment: What you could do is have it by default return `undefined` and then inside the if statement body have its type be `string`... but the problem is that they are functions and they're just gonna stack as overloads. So I found [this](https://tsplay.dev/mb0ePw) workaround which uses getters instead. If this is good enough I'll post it as an answer. I only found `unknown` to work; `undefined`, `null`, `never` won't work correctly.

Comment: @catgirlkelly looks interesting - give me some time to validate and I'll circle back as soon as possible!

Comment: @catgirlkelly just too a look, basically we cannot use the function - I think it's definitely a workaround, but the type in the `else` statement is set to `unknown` which is also not ideal. It's also not super clear for me what is the return type for `hasMatch` but I am not super use to this syntax - I would still not use this solution on the other hand... it feels like this is something missing with TypeScript that could potentially be useful?

Comment: It's a type guard. I think you should open an issue or update an existing one about this on the GitHub repository.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, this is not feasible with TypeScript today.

@catgirlkelly provided a few workarounds that are interesting to try but all with different drawbacks (when they work):

- https://tsplay.dev/mb0ePw
- https://tsplay.dev/w2aOxW
- https://tsplay.dev/WoGdjW

But as we can tell from the [issue I opened](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48926) on TypeScript's GitHub similar issues have been opened on this topic, since at least [2016](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13086) and due to the complexity, no solution was provided yet.

Comment: `now` => `not`, right?

Comment: Oops fixed my typo! Thanks